# XmlReader parsing single line of xml

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have an xml file, even though it's not in the correct format. I just want to retrieve the values since that is my main goal. Also the file is one single line. The file looks something like this.

```
<Real64List>...numbers value....</Real64List> <Real64List>...numbers value...</Real64List><Uint32List>...numbers value..</Uint32List>.
```

I was able to first the first part of , but when I'm trying to parse the second part and third part I get an error "multiple root on line 1". So how can I parse the second part of Real64List and Uint32List. Thanks in advance!

Here is the snippet of the code I'm using.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("generator_0000001.xml"))
{
   List<float> vertex = new List<float>();
   List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3>();
   while (!reader.EOF)
   { 
     if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Real64List")
     {
       string xmlValue = reader.Value;
       string[] coordinates = xmlValue.Split(',');
       for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; i++)
       {
         vertex.Add(float.Parse(coordinates[i]));
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < vertex.Count; i += 3)
       {
         var myVect = new Vector3(vertex[i], vertex[i + 1], vertex[i + 2]);
         verticesList.Add(myVect);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you already know the structure of the line, maybe fixing it (by adding a root node) and then parsing it normally is the simplest way.

Comment: That's not valid xml.  Valid xml has one root node

Comment: I know is not a valid XML, but this is a file that was given to me that another program is spitting out. Apparently this is what it's spitting out so I just have to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert those XmlElements into a new XML node.  Then you should be able to parse it as valid XML.  Some straightforward examples can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild(v=vs.110).aspx)